# facebook's object debugger says 'we're sorry, but something went wrong'

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I set ogp tags on my website.
Even though it should be OK, facebook's object debugger says 'something went wrong'.

Here's my website.
https://makeyourownemblem.herokuapp.com/showemblem/2

BTW I use following gems.
meta-tags, sitemap_generator

Could you give me some advice?